# Rails: How "email_field" differs from "text_field"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, textfield, emailfield

I understand that `text_field` creates an input field of type `text`, while `email_field` creates an input field of type `email`.

But, what is the difference between these two input types ?

Say I have a client model while a client has an email. Should I use `email_field` here ?

Comment: Input type=email is an HTML5 property which validates the input is an email address.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html

Comment: Little update, email validation now works on most newer browsers. Use email_field to get free browser based validation without script.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The email field is the new html 5 input which right now behaves the same on most of the machines with the exception of a few mobile devices such as the iphone where it switches to a different keyboard.

You can find more about it by googling `html5 email field`.

It's just a touch of finesse which some users will appreciate.